# Slice a list such that the result has the 2 elements before and 2 elements after the subject and a constant result length?

Tags: python

Given this sorted array:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

I want to slice up this array so that there are always 5 elements.  2 above and 2 below.  I went with:

```
>>> [x[i-2:i+2] for i, v in enumerate(x)]
```

This results in:

```
[[], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

The problems with this are:

1. There are 4 elements per group, not 5
2. Not every group has 2 above and 2 below.
3. The first and last groups are special cases. I do not want
   blanks at the front.  What I want to see is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` as the first group and then `['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`
   as the second group.

I also played around with clamping the slices.

First I [defined a clamp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092528/how-to-clamp-an-integer-to-some-range) like so:

```
>>> def clamp(n, smallest, largest): return max(smallest, min(n, largest))
```

Then, I applied the function like so:

```
>>> [x[clamp(i-2, 0, i):clamp(i+2, i, len(x))] for i, v in enumerate(x)]
```

But it didn't really work out so well:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

Am I even barking up the right tree?

I found two SO articles about this issue, but they didn't address these edge cases:

[Search a list for item(s)and return x number of surrounding items in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413684/search-a-list-for-itemsand-return-x-number-of-surrounding-items-in-python)

[efficient way to find several rows above and below a subset of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150096/efficient-way-to-find-several-rows-above-and-below-a-subset-of-data)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `[x[i-2:i+3] for i in range(2, len(x) - 2)]` Also why not just do 4 elements after the subject? `[x[i:i+5] for i in range(len(x) - 4)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

you may want to use range(len(x)) instead of enumerate, then you will avoid having to unpack the result.

If anyone need to understand slice notation, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/9296057)

Then, you can filter the list inside the comprehension

```py
x = list('abcdefghijklmno')
[ x[i-2:i+2+1] for i in range(len(x)) if len(x[i-2:i+2+1]) == 5 ]
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], ['j', 'k', 'l', '`
# On python 3.8 you can use the walrus operator!!!
[ y for i in range(len(x)) if len(y:=x[i-2:i+2+1]) == 5 ]
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']]
```

Comment: The walrus operator!  Yes!

Comment: Answering the question was just an excuse. The central point was to mention the walrus operator. For future curious visitors: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/